# Getting error - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text cannot be null or empty

Tags: java, swing, ibm-watson

Trying to use Text Area to send String to IBM Watson.

Could do this by hard coding String. I want to be able to input my own text in JTextArea.

Comment: Judging by the error, it looks like the String variable "text" is either null or emtpy when you call Profile profile = service.getProfile(text).execute(); which is not allowed. Perhaps try passing in a hard-coded string literal to the getProfile method just to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @dave823 Cheers Dave. Code works with hard-coded string. Just trying to figure out how to do it with user input.

Comment: I see the problem. You are populating the "text" variable on initializing. You just need to move that line String text = textArea.getText(); inside the actionPerformed method.

Comment: Excellent! Works a treat! Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `String text = textArea.getText();` inside the `actionPerformed` method like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = textArea.getText();
            Profile profile = service.getProfile(text).execute();  
            System.out.println(profile);


                }
```